# Using Two "For" at the same time

Tags: c#, for-loop

Well, I'm trying to use two commands "For" at the same time.

The code:

```
public static void SendToMap(string map, string packet)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Clients.Count; i++)
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < Globals.Player_HighIndex; i2++)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
            Console.Write(i2);
            if (PStruct.character[i2, PStruct.player[i2].SelectedChar].Map == map)
            {
                if (Listen.Clients[i].Index == i2)
                {
                    Clients[Listen.Clients[i].ListIndex].TCPClient.Client.SendBufferSize = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(packet);
                    Clients[Listen.Clients[i].ListIndex].TCPClient.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(packet));
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The Globals.Player_HighIndex value is 1, and Clients.Count is 0, ie, I want the command to be executed as follows:

```
(0,0) (0,1)
```

What is done:

```
(0,0)
```

Anyone have tips or a resolution?

Comment: What's the value of Globals.Player_HighIndex? Is it zero by any chance?

Comment: use a debugger and step through your code...

Comment: Note that "`Clients.Count` is 0" seem to contradict with output you are getting - execution should not even enter first loop if it would be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end your loop too early. you need <=.

```
for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= Globals.Player_HighIndex; i2++)
```